# Проблема с отображением русских букв ruby

Tags: ruby

Помогите пожалуйста!Кодировка utf - 8, но русские буквы не выводятся. Почему так? Что я делаю не так? Вот код:
puts "Привет! Как тебя зовут?"
name = gets.encode("UTF-8").chomp
puts "Привет," + name + ", как дела?"
[[image: Не выводятся русские буквыНе выводятся русские буквы]

Comment: Если вы при чтении делаете `encode`, то при печати надо делать `decode`.

Comment: Можно пример кода с 'decode' пожалуйста?

Comment: Никакого `decode` нет. Извините. Ниже дал ответ. Протестируйте на Windows. У меня под рукой только Linux и английский Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы читаете текст и преобразуете его во внутреннюю кодировку, то перед печатью его нужно преобразовать обратно. Узнать что это за "обратно" можно двумя способами: спросить кодировку у самой строки после чтения или использовать `Encoding.default_external`:

```
v = gets # читаем строку как есть
puts "v.enconding #{v.encoding.inspect}"
puts "Encoding.default_external #{Encoding.default_external.inspect}"

# преобразуем имя в UTF-8
name = v.encode("UTF-8").chomp

# преобразуем имя обратно
name_de = name.encode(Encoding.default_external)

puts
puts "Привет, #{name_de}, как дела?"
```

Если дружите с английским вот короткий обзор: [Understanding Ruby: String Encoding, ASCII & Unicode](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/05/ruby-ascii-unicode/).